# How do I get cell data from a javascript variable containing a <tr> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables and the table tools plugin. I can have the selected row returned as a javascript variable. With that variable I want to get the value of a specific cell in each row. I am not sure at all how to do this though. This is basically what I have

```
var rowData = TableTools.fnGetInstance( 'tableID' ).fnGetSelected();
```

And what I want to do is something like rowData.children('td'), that doesn't work, but something to that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var cellValue = $("#tableID").dataTable().fnGetData(rowData, colIndex);
```

Where colIndex is whatever column you want to get the value of (this includes hidden cells).

If you don't care about hidden cells, you could also do:

```
var cellValue = $(rowData).children("td")...
```

Comment: How could I make sure to do this on whichever row the user selects?

Comment: Ahhh...sorry.  Edited my answer.  The first parameter to fnGetData should be your rowData variable.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. Just in case anyone uses this as a reference, the actual solution is "var cellValue = $("#tableID").dataTable().fnGetData(rowData[0], colIndex);